# converting String to Date swift3 ios10

Tags: ios, swift

why does this return a nil? detailDate is in this format: 
"Wednesday, November 23, 2016 at 2:01 PM"

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy' at 'h:mm a"
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
let dateForCalendar = dateFormatter.date(from: detailDate!)
```

I believe it returns a nil because my `dateFormat` is not the same as what my `detailDate format` is, but I don't understand why it's different.

Comment: Don't set the `dateStyle`, just the `dateFormat`. Also set the formatter's locale to `en_US_POSIX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After assigning a `DateFormat` why are you changing the date style ?

remove,

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
```

and it will work,

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy' at 'h:mm a"
let dateForCalendar = dateFormatter.date(from: detailDate!)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   let detailDate = "Wednesday, November 23, 2016 at 2:01 PM"
    let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy' at 'h:mm a"
    let strDate = dateformatter.date(from: detailDate)
    print(strDate!)
```

try this , it's work proper

Comment: 1) Please don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how your answer solves the issue. 2) How is you answer different than the one that was previously posted? Don't post duplicate answers.